# Can anyone post a beginner's guide for RUSE?

Tags: ruse

I just installed R.U.S.E.

I tried to play the first game, but, due to the fact that tutorial is still missing, I am a bit lost.

I suppose that I have to destroy the enemy base, but how? What are that buildings with yellow containers? What I should build first? And, what are all the cities/villages I see around used for?

Can you please post a 10-step (or more if you like) guide to help a beginner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any decent R.U.S.E. free strategy guide?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9195/is-there-any-decent-r-u-s-e-free-strategy-guide)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those "yellow buildings" are unclaimed supply depots. You need to create a supply depot and you can move the map around to get select which depot you want to use. Best use depots near your HQ to speed up cash flow. Cities are merely cover for various units and so provide a terrain advantage and that's all... and they add to the ambience of the map.

You can check out the official strategy guide [here](http://store.steampowered.com/app/22812/). Google brings up [a lot of results](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=RUSE+Strategy+guide) too.

This is my beginners guide.

RUSE like most RTS games involves acquiring resources, building stuff, then killing stuff. If you're interested in the quickbattles or multiplayer options this is how I got started.

1. Build a couple of Supply Depots. The faster you gain cash, the faster you can build. Pick ones far from the enemy so it's harder for them to over-run/destroy them.
2. You should have a RUSE card available so use "Blitz" to make the following happen a lot faster. You want to collect supplies and establish bases ASAP.
3. Build Barracks. Build a couple of recons and send them out immediately... intel, intel, intel!
4. Build an Armor Base (Tanks) Start building heavy tanks. Put tanks near bridges, they're choke points, can make a good kill zone.
5. Build an anti-tank base. You can create anti-tank/anti-air batteries.
6. Build anti-air to protect your buildings
7. Build a few tank destroyers. Bundle them with your tanks. One supports the other in the face of other tanks.
   8a. If you have spare cash. Do the upgrades for your tanks.
8. By this time you should have some cash, so build an Airbase and send out aerial recon deep into enemy territory. But watch out for their anti-air.
9. Create some heavy soldiers, (Rangers). (You will have to do "research" as it's an upgrade)

That covers getting started. Now lets start blowing stuff up!

1. Use a "Spy" Ruse card to find your opposition.
2. Target his supply dumps if they are near you. Starve the opposition of resources if you can. Or place light tanks along his supply lines, stopping the trucks is just as good.
3. Create some howitzers. These are good from a distance and support your tanks. Just keep them back from the front line.
4. Send some tanks and harass a bit. get used to engaging.
5. Use a "Fake Offensive" RUSE Card to draw the enemy to another part of the map and expose resources.
6. Put your heavy troops in Cities or the woods as they have bonuses for ambushes and defence automatically.
7. I found that mid-way through a campaign, if the opposition gets a lot of planes, you're in trouble, so build at least 4 combat fighters and 4 fighter-bombers. But recon areas before flying into them because anti-air makes short work of air-power.

You will keep getting RUSE Cards periodically (while your HQ is intact). I found I was using Blitz a lot. When launching a major offensive into an area, use Blitz to get in there fast.

When you do multiplayer, it helps to have voice chat between you and your team mate.
You can build multiple bases of the same type, like armor bases and barracks and this speeds up production.

Play against the AI first before running out and taking on humans, because humans will kill you a lot faster and that is not fun after a couple of hours.

Prototype bases produce interesting stuff that basically is tougher and can kill lots of stuff. But this is only worthwhile once you have great supply.

I found that I was creating secondary HQ's to collect resources far away. This speeds up the cash flow, but you have to consider protection of it to.

The campaign is annoying with some silly story and plot. It ruins the game play for me, but some people think this stuff is worthwhile. I don't know why game designers do this because it's always (always) tacky dialog,  and computer animated characters just make it look like a thunderbirds show.

There is heaps more to this game, and there are other (and better?) strategies to. That's the cool thing about RUSE. Pitting your strategy against theirs and adapting to the unpredictable... have fun!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try watching [commented gameplay on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/user/kknev#p/c/871280221C26A610). Helped me a lot.