# Is there any decent R.U.S.E. free strategy guide?

Tags: ruse

I haven't been able to find a decent free guide on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruse Wiki is a great place to start, its free, community driven, and should continue to expand. You can find it [here](http://ruse.wikia.com/wiki/R.U.S.E._Wiki), and you find can a list of in game tactics [here](http://ruse.wikia.com/wiki/In-game_Tactics).

Also, Arqade is a another great place for strategy because you can answer focused questions. To get an idea of the quality content you can get for free, look at the Starcraft 2 question: [What are the popular build orders for Protoss in StarCraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/875/1770)

Answer (score 0):

here is the actual 2013 Ruse Guide with all the information (e.g. Speed, Strength, Distance) about the different units like Tanks, Anti Tanks, Aircraft, Anti Aircraft, Infantry and others

It comes along with a Strategy Guide with Tactics for all the different  Countries